# Reference for approximation criterion for convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I'm studying the article "Some Rigorous Results on the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick Spin Glass Model" (1987, Aizenman, Lebowitz and Ruelle).
In the beginning of section 3 of the article, they cite the following result:

[image]

And as a reference, they give Feller's "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Vol II".

**Can someone refer me to the location in Feller's book, or another resource, where I can find a statement and proof of this result?**

Thank you